# JavaScript remove EventListener by Event reference

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I am storing an event in a variable like so:

```
var lastEvent;

document.getElementById("button-1").addEventListener("click", function(){

     // Stores the event to the variable lastEvent

     lastEvent = arguments[0];

});
```

I now want to remove the event listener by referencing **lastEvent**.

```
 document.getElementById("button-2").addEventListener("click", function(){

     // This doesn't work, obviously

    lastEvent.removeEventListener();

});
```

Any Idea if this is possible?

Comment: In any case, you can only use [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) with a reference to the event listener that was added, not the event that was fired, so what you want isn't possible without saving the handler function somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I wanted to know — if this was in any way possible. I will find a workaround. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove an event handler you need:

- The element to which the element handler is attached
- The function you want to remove

So you would need something like…

```
let lastEvent;
const trackingHandler = (event) => {
    lastEvent = event
};
const removingHandler = (event) => {
    const element = lastEvent.target;
    element.removeEventListener(trackingHandler);
};
document.getElementById("button-1").addEventListener("click", trackingHandler);
document.getElementById("button-2").addEventListener("click", removingHandler);
```

… and you would need extra logic to distinguish between multiple *trackingHandler* functions if there were more than one of them.